# How to redirect http to https in JBoss EAP 6.4?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, redirect, jboss-eap-6

Here how to set **substitution** to any address so that I can use it in AWS Application Load Balancer.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https"  enable-lookups="false" secure="true" />
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
    <rewrite pattern="^/(.*)$" substitution="https://localhost:443/$1" flags="RL">
        <condition test="%{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </rewrite>               
    <alias name="localhost"/>
    <alias name="example.com"/>
</virtual-server>
```

I want like

```
<rewrite pattern="^/(.*)$" substitution="https://%HOST_NAME%" flags="RL">
    <condition test="%{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps to redirect from http to https in EAP 6,

Add **redirect-port="443"** to **http connector** as follows :

```
<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" redirect-port="443"/>
```

Change the socket-binding of https to 443 as follows :

```
<socket-binding name="https" port="443"/>
```

Configure https connector in EAP 6,

```
 <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
                <ssl name="ssl" key-alias="mykey" password="password" certificate-key-file="/path/to/keystore.jks"/>
        </connector>
```

Edit the web.xml of application as follows:-

```
<web-app>   
       <security-constraint>
         <web-resource-collection>
             <web-resource-name>Application</web-resource-name>
             <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
         </web-resource-collection>
         <user-data-constraint>
             <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
         </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    </web-app>
```

Comment: Still it is redirecting to **http** only, its not working on **https**. Modified **web.xml** also

Comment: `<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" redirect-port="443"/>
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" enable-lookups="false" secure="true">
    <ssl name="https" key-alias="testKey" password="password" certificate-key-file="C:\keys\test.keystore"/>
</connector>`

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me (change in configruation/standalone-full.xml):

```
        <filters>
            <rewrite name="http-to-https" target="https://${jboss.qualified.host.name}:8443%U" redirect="true"/>
        </filters>
```